# How to talk about an appointment that was set in the past for a future time?

Tags: past-tense, future-tense, time

I was wondering if the following sentence makes sense. My main purpose is to learn the structure and I just wrote this as an example:

> The earliest appointment she gave me is this Friday.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Except it kind of sounds like she gave you more than one appointment, the first of which is Friday. "The earliest appointment she could give me is this Friday" sounds (to me) more like you have only one appointment, except it then is less definite about whether you actually accepted, unless it is known from context that you did. "My appointment is this Friday; I couldn't get one sooner" is pretty unambiguous...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your are very close.  I think it sounds more natural to say:

> The earliest appointment she had available was for this Friday.

Answer (score 2):

*The earliest appointment she could give me was for this Friday.*

You can also use *was able to* instead of *could*.